# Responsive web-app design related to user behaviour

Tags: ipad, user-interface

we built a webapp. We do not know who will actually use the app. Some will use it on the computer some on the iPad. Moreover one user will log in and will spent some time to accomplish all given tasks. On the iPad it is obvious that expierenced users will expect zoom and wipe effects, unexpierenced users will prefer desktop-similiar behaviour. I thought I will try to implement an algorithm which detects how expierenced a user is and the user will be categorized to the related profile.

Where can I read about this topic? Thanks in advance for some links to relevant articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did some research and 'User modeling' seems like a good start.